# How to calculate sum for selected values from database in java?

Tags: java, sum

I have selected the values from db by using hibernate and i want to calculate the sum for specified columns. my table contains `

```
 Id(int) transportname (string)  idletime (string)
  1       xxx                     04:00
  1        yy                     05:00
  2       xxx                     09:01
```

I have selected it by using hibernate query. I want to calculate the sum for idle column for each id. How can i do that by using java.

Comment: Why don't you do it in the HQL itself, instead of trying to do in Java?

Comment: I need to calculate the sum in the java code itself,and send it as a field to the report

Answer (score 0):

You could read the results in a loop, maintaining a mapping of idle values by id, something like this:

```
Map<Integer,Integer> idleById = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
while (// results) {
  int id = // read from results
  int idle = // read from results
  Integer value = idleById.get(id);
  if value != null) {
     value = new Integer(value.intValue() + idle);
  } else {
     value = new Integer(idle);
  }
  idleById.put(id, value);
}
```